# Weird issues in setting style using JavaScript while using a DOCTYPE

Tags: javascript, html, css, doctype

I am trying to add a `<div>` using JavaScript and then change its width/height/top/left attributes. But when I use the XHTML 1 Transitional doctype, it stops working.

This is how I am creating the `<div>`:

```
var div=document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(div);
div.innerHTML='<div id="myID" style="z-index:9998;border: 1px solid #000000;
border-radius:3px;position: absolute; display: block;top:-10000;left:-10000; 
width:400; height:400;"></div>';
```

So initially `myDiv` is not visible to user as its left and top are out of the screen

Then on some click action I am doing the following:

```
var myDiv=document.getElementById("myID");
myDiv.style.top=200;
myDiv.style.left=200;
```

This works fine if I do not put a doctype in the HTML. As soon as I put the doctype, it stops working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

With the doctype, it stops accepting top/left/width/height values. But if I set the width/height/top/left values with units (i.e. px) then it works fine.

```
myDiv.style.top="200px";
myDiv.style.left="200px";
```

So, what is the impact of the doctype on the execution of JavaScript while modifying the style (or may be other things as well)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using raw numbers is technically invalid, even if the browser is letting you get away with it when you're not using a doctype (browsers do lots of funky things when you don't use a doctype).

The style properties really are like the CSS properties, strings with units on them. So "200px" is correct, 200 is incorrect. The properties ([`left`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-left), for instance) can be [lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-length) like "200px" or "10em", or [percentages](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-percentage) (or `auto` or `inherit`). (Those links are to the CSS 2.1 spec.)

You also need to include units in your string when creating the `myID` div:

```
div.innerHTML = '<div id="myID" style="z-index:9998; ' +
    'border: 1px solid #000000; ' +
    'border-radius:3px;' +
    'position: absolute;' +
    'display: block;' +
    'top:-10000px;' +     // here
    'left:-10000px;' +    // here
    'width:400px;' +      // here
    'height:400px;"' +    // and here
    '></div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `DOCTYPE` tells the browser that you are using a specific standard (in your case, XHTML 1.0) - the browser then uses an exact render mode (instead of the [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) that it would use without a DOCTYPE).

This means that it will interpret your code much more strictly - the sizes should always have a unit with them (200px, 1.2em etc...). Just a number is meaningless, so the browser will ignore these values when not in quirks mode.